# How to control whether a resource exists in Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-scheduler

I am building with Terraform a Cloud Scheduler job that will hit a service deployed in Cloud Run. Because the service and the scheduler are deployed in different pipelines, it is possible that the service does not exist yet when running the scheduler pipeline. This is why I am using data "google_cloud_run_service" to retrieve the service and then control whether it exists in the scheduler block. It is here that I don't find the right syntax to use in count.

```
data "google_cloud_run_service" "run-service" {
  name = "serv-${var.project_env}"
  location = var.region
}

resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {
  count       = length(data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service.status)
  name        = "snap-job-${var.project_env}"
  description = "Call write API on my service"
  schedule    = "* * * * *"
  time_zone   = "Etc/UTC"

  http_target {
    http_method = "GET"
    uri         = "${data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service.status[0].url}/write"
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = google_service_account.sa_scheduler.email
    }
  }

  depends_on = [google_app_engine_application.app]
}
```

- The above `length(data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service.status)` control will not make any effect, and Terraform tries to create the scheduler even though there is no service defined.
- I have also tried other variations with similar result such as `length(data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service.status[0]) > 0 ? 1 : 0`.
- Other options that I tried will not work either with different errors:

  - `data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service ? 1 : 0`: data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service is object with 9 attributes;The condition expression must be of type bool
  - `data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service.status[0].url ? 1 : 0`: data.google_cloud_run_service.run-service is object with 9 attributes;The condition expression must be of type bool

Comment: The data source will either return the one `google_cloud_run_service` it can find or the terraform plan will completely fail, it will not output no resource that you can then handle using count. The way you want the different deployments to interact is not how terraform is supposed to be run.

Comment: Actually, the terraform plan does not fail when the `google_cloud_run_service` is not available. Why terraform is not supposed to run in this way?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16380 : *"The sort of dynamic decision-making that is being requested here runs counter to Terraform's design goals, since it makes the configuration a description of what might possibly be rather than what is. We are not going to change the behavior of data sources when the response is empty or 404, and will close this issue."*!